# Как вывести точки на яндекс карте по адресам?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

подскажите - как вывести точки на яндекс карте по адресу магазина а не координатам?

```
function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true
        });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });

}
```

в доке нашел только по координатам

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]
      },
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

а мне нужно, например, *Москв, МКАД, Осташковское шоссе, Мытищинская Ярмарка Строй Двор Яуза ТСК 2, павильон 2-18*

Comment: **Aslero**, сначала нужно геокодировать адрес магазина и получить его координаты. Затем вывести точки по координатам

Comment: а где это в доке или может пример, я что-то не нашел как это сделать

Comment: **Aslero,** посмотрите здесь `https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/`

Answer (score 0):

Для добавления метки на карту координаты обязательны. Из исходных данных их надо получить геокодированием.

Только надо понимать, что существует два различных случая.

1. **У вас есть нормальный почтовый адрес здания.**
   В этом случае вам следует использовать прямое [геокодирование](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/) адреса. Пример на JS API есть в песочнице: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode
   Имейте в виду, что всякие лишние комментарии (как проехать, номер павильона, телефоны и пр.) скажутся на качестве геокодирования и могут показать не то, что надо.
2. **У вас есть название организации (возможно с адресом)**
   В этом случае нужно использовать [поиск по организациям](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosearch/). Пример использования его в JS API также есть в песочнице: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo
   В поисковом запросе также стоит убрать лишнюю информацию.